# Error trying to install mode to cancel the program

Tags: inno-setup

Good afternoon, I have the following problem in my installer made ​​in Inno Setup program, attempting to cancel the installation of my program the following error occurs: 
Runtime Error (at 2:86): Internal error: An attempt was made ​​to expand the "app" constant before it was initialized.

can someone enlighten me this error?

Comment: Please [edit] to include your .iss file so we can see what you're doing. The error is pretty clear - something is trying to use the `{app}` constant before it has been assigned a value. Without the script file, we can't see where that might be happening.

Comment: Additional info as you havent posted your script: In case if you have to use `Application Path` before `{app}` constant has value assigned you could try `ExpandConstant(WizardDirValue)`.